# CSS Align image with input

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a little problem with my css, I can't align an image with a text input field. The site is live at http://jocolina.com/picemon/pokelocator.php

The CSS I have for the text input and image is:

```
#loginUTC{
  width:30%;
  height: 60px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight: bold;

  /*margin: 0 auto;*/
  border-color: #336688;
}

#magniIMG{
  display: inline;
  height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#locator{
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  height:60px;
}
```

Where loginUTC is the text input, magniIMG is the image I want to algin with the input, and locator is the div in which both of the elements are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set both elements to `vertical-align: bottom;`.

```
#loginUTC{
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

#magniIMG{
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use margin-bottom in negative at image that will fix it

```
#magniIMG {
    display: inline;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: -18px;
}
```

Comment: Yes I also found that -18 was the solution, it is however very dependent on the screen, and might not work in mobile

Comment: @JoColina no it doesnt depend on screen. it depends on code and pixels will work fine till you have same heights setting. you can view by resizing browsers :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use floats to align the form elements with images like you are trying to achieve here. You'll also need to add some widths to the containing element and the input to align everything. Try -

```
#locator {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
height: 60px;
width: 545px;
}

#loginUTC {
height: 60px;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 30px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
/* margin: 0 auto; */
border-color: #336688;
float: left;
}

#magniIMG {
/* display: inline; */
height: 60px;
cursor: pointer;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: This will break the fluid layout though.

Comment: what happens then if it goes to left